# hiding li elements of specific classes

Tags: jquery, list, hide

I have this specific bit of jquery where I want to hide only the li elements specific to those classes.

I used this bit of jquery, problem is its hiding all li elements on the page, not just the ones I want it to.  I am not sure how to write it so that it will only hide children li elements - can anyone help with this.

Many thanks in advance

```
$("#image,#image1,#image2,#image3,#image4,#image5,#image6,#image7,#image8,#image9,#image10").add("li").hide();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "children li"? Nested lists?

Comment: Instead of listing all those IDs explicitly, why don't you use a class?

Comment: Hi   I am trying to get it to display only the stone colours for specific design choices.  The original code worked well, except for hiding the top menu li, but using find will not re-hide those stone colour options that are not required for the pattern http://www.pinkequine.com/shop/product_info.php?products_id=35

Comment: Here is another using the same script but with the .li as per the original coding. If you change the bespoke pattern it should remove the select boxes that are not relevant to that pattern. http://www.pinkequine.com/shop/product_info.php?products_id=36

Comment: @barmar, they are all different classes because each one relates to a stone image and that image is then placed into an image position to create a pattern.  I had to do different classes for each possible stone position because it didnt like me re-using the select box id's for different patterns.

Comment: Elements can have multiple classes. So they can have different classes for the stone image, but a common class for this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$("#image,#image1,#image2,#image3,#image4,#image5,#image6,#image7,#image8,#image9,#image10").find("li").hide();
```

You may want to shorten that selector [`attribute startsWith`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='image']").find("li").hide();
```

Comment: I am ticking your answer because I found the shortening of the selector really useful - I fixed it by using UL which had a class set for it by image-picker as the li had no class  $("[id^='image']").add("ul.thumbnails.image_picker_selector").hide();